# Making two brachos at once

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

When eating a food that requires two brachos (Crispix, some salads etc.) I was told that the correct procedure is to make one bracha on part, eat it and then make another bracha on the next part. Why can't I just make two (or more) brachos and then eat everything?

Comment: Perhaps you can (CYLOR). Isn't the *shehechiyanu* blessing recited as part of the kiddush on Yomim Tovim recited after the *borei p'ri hagafen* but before the wine is drunk? To me, that seems like a *hefseik* (an interruption - see Monica Cellio's [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16390/1059)). But we don't worry about that, for whatever reason. Maybe because that is part of the *nusach* of kiddush. So too here, why shouldn't we say e.g. regarding Crispix that reciting two blessings one after the other is part of the *nusach habrachot* for that food?

Comment: @AdamMosheh There is no nussach haberachot for that food because it isn't one food! If it was one food, then the rules of ikar and tafel would apply and only one bracha would be said. The whole issue here assumes it is two foods so two separate brachot need to be said. Hence each would be an interruption of the other.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's what I'm having trouble understanding. I'm not making a hefsek that is unrelated to what I'm doing (eating crispix). Would this be similar to making 2 brachos on lighting the menorah?

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave - Yes, exactly!  Or three blessings on the first night.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave I think the issue is defining how broadly we view 'what you are doing'. Indeed your goal is to eat multiple foods (and they are multiple foods, else you wouldn't need two brachot), but each doesn't relate to the other _halachikly_. The Shulchan Aruch rules 167:6 that if you speak about things related to "_that which you blessed over_" then it is not a hefsek. In any event, the Rama notes that this is only bedieved and we try to avoid any 'interruptions' whatsoever, so either way you would not be allowed to do this trick lechatchila.

Comment: Okay, so admit that they aren't two separate foods.  Say that the mezonot is ikar because zayin minim should not be tafel.  I don't see why that shouldn't work.  But even if they are two separate foods, it should be fine because you are eating them both *b'vas achas*.  Okay, so the ReM"A says that, but what if you are Sephardic?  Then would the halacha go as I said it?

Comment: OK I think we need some more background to make sense of this. If you eat 2 different things together as 1, then you only say one bracha based on which is the main thing (ikar). As I understand it, the reason many do the trick of separating the pieces in mixtures like salad and Crispix is because they are in a doubt about if there is one main and one secondary, and even if so, which is the main ingredient (note that despite its being Mezonot, rice is not one of the 5 grains)?

Comment: Thus people purposefully separate the 2 and eat each individually to obligate themselves in both brachot. So in this case you are not intending to eat both b'vas achas. If you did and said both brachot before eating the whole salad/Crispik, either one be levatala as unnecasary OR the second would be a hefsek to the first because the two are distinctly seperate entities. You can't say they are one entity but say two brachot, and you can't say two brachot and expect the two to be related.

Comment: But splitting it up into two wouldn't be unnecessary (levatalah) because you are saying it to eat that thing individually.

Answer (score 4):

If you make both brachot before eating, you are introducing an [interruption](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/03_interruptions.html) between the first bracha and the eating to which it applies.  We make brachot as close as possible to the act that calls for the bracha.

This answer assumes that you are eating two (different) types of food as separate entities.  If the food is really one combined item, then you would say only one bracha based on the rules of precedence.  See @DoubleAA's explanation in the comments on the question.)

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with Monica Cellio's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16390/1059) because I think that a hefseik should be permitted in cases where there is no hesech hadaat.  For example, the *shehechiyanu* blessing in Yontif Kiddush is recited after the *borei p'ri hagafen* but before the wine is drunk.  So too here, we should be able to say e.g. regarding Crispix cereal that reciting two blessings one after the other is part of the *nusach habrachot* for that food and there is no hesech hadaat like kiddush on yontif.

(This hefseik is not unrelated to what you are doing. See Identitytheft-Dave's comment on the initial question.)

Comment: What if you said HaEtz on an apple, and then had a phone conversation with someone, but all the time were holding the apple and aware of it? Would that still work?

Comment: Theoretically, yes it should still work!  Practically, I wouldn't do it myself though because I wouldn't be able to control my thoughts to keep them on task.

Comment: But DoubleAA, you are not having a phone conversation between saying the first blessing and eating.  You are just saying another blessing.  That is a short enough time period to control your thoughts.

Comment: This hefseik is not unrelated to what you are doing.  See Identitytheft-Dave's comment on the initial question.

Comment: Hesech hadaat is irrelevant. The Shulchan Aruch clearly rules in OC 167:6 that speaking about unrelated things requires a new bracha. This answer is wrong. -1

Comment: It IS unrelated. What your doing when you say mezonot is trying to eat the rice side of the Crispix. See my comments on the question for more detail.

Comment: Yes, but the apple example is not the one that my answer is resolving.  If the only words you speak are the second bracha, then that is definitely NOT considered an unrelated thing.  You are not trying to eat this side or that side.  That is not normal derech achilah.  You are just trying to eat it.

Comment: What if you are trying to eat an apple while talking on the phone?

Comment: I thought you are talking theoretically.  Ideally, you shouldn't be.  But what if you are calling your rabbi to ask if you should say a shechiyanu on that apple (you forgot to ask before you said *borei p'ri ha'eitz*), but you don't have hesech hadaat in the meantime?

Comment: That is related to the THING YOU SAID THE BRACHA ON which is the apple. Just like you can wash after hamotzi if you forgot and you can seperate terumot if you forgot.

Comment: יאכל מיד ולא ישיח בין ברכה לאכילה ואם שח צריך לחזור ולברך אלא אם כן היתה השיחה בדברים מענין דברים שמברכין עליו כגון שבירך על הפת וקודם שאכל אמר הביאו מלח או ליפתן תנו לפלוני לאכול תנו מאכל לבהמה וכיוצא באלו אינו צריך לברך.

Comment: **בדברים מענין דברים שמברכין עליו**

Comment: things related to the things that you are saying the blessings on.  not related to the blessings, but the food itself.  you need salt for that bread.  you might need shehechiyanu for that apple.

Comment: I agree. I think it is muttar to call your rabbi to ask if you need shehechiyanu. I don't think you can say a bracha on an unrelated piece of food.

Comment: Yes, but this is completely related.  So why are you disagreeing with me?

Comment: Because it is completely unrelated to the bracha (I'm not talking about physical proximity). If the two foods were brachot-ly related then only one bracha would be required per ikar and tafel. They are not so they get two brachot which are not related to each other. What makes you say the brachot are related? They are on different things! Would you say I can also say a shehakol on my orange juice? I like orange juice for breakfast with my cereal.

Comment: People generally put milk in your cereal, not orange juice.  And you are not eating cereal in order to drink the milk.  That is why the milk is tafel.  If you put OJ into cereal but you wanted to eat two separate things together in the same bite but wanted to eat them both (both are ikar), then maybe.  Tzarich iyun, CYLOR.  Here, you intend to eat both sides of each Crispix *b'vat achat* (both in one fell swoop), which is the same as the OJ in cereal case (AFAICT).

Comment: By the way, thanks for arguing with me.  It is really helping me to see all the aspects to each side of the argument.

Comment: (OJ in cereal?! Uch! I was talking about a glass of OJ on the side.) See my comments to the question

Comment: is there a maskana here?

Comment: -1 L'chatchila, if there is no _need_ to make a hefsek, you may not interrupt. B'dieved, you do not need to repeat a b'racha so long as the interruption was relevant. Since a b'racha on the second food is not relevant to eating the first food, I doubt that it is acceptable even b'dieved.

Comment: @DoubleAA - If the glass of OJ was on the side, then why would you be consuming both cereal and OJ *b'vat achat*?  (Also, how can you have OJ and cereal in the same meal - one is acidic and the other basic!)

Comment: @Fred - There is a need, because eating a spoonful of Crispix is the normal derech achilah.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave - I am still under the conviction that my reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave - In such a case where they are eaten together, you only make a single b'racha (on the ikkar) anyway.

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave, and @ Fred, So what was the initial question addressing anyway if one only blesses on the ikar in the first place?

Comment: @AdamMosheh a case where there is no ikar/tafel, like crispix

Comment: @Identitytheft-Dave - I thought that zayin minim can never be tafel?  And although it is exactly half-and-half, even rov can be tafel when there is some other ikar.  But they are both ikarim since they are both intended for eating.

Comment: @AdamMosheh - You don't make a separate b'rachah on the milk unless you want to have some of the milk separately. Certain foods are chashuv enough that you make a b'rachah even if you didn't otherwise want to eat it separately. Still, since you'd have to make another b'rachah in that case, you would have to isolate it and eat it separately at first.

Comment: Rice is not 7 minim though.  Crispix being half corn and half rice...  Would you really prefer the corn half enough to eat it separately?  You have to prefer one to make it more chashuv, but if you don't, then what is the ikar?  What if you prefer both evenly?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, Your proof from shehecheyanu of kiddush is no proof.  The reason it is not a hefsek is because lechatechila shehecheyanu requires wine.  Eruvin 40b discusses whether zeman requires a kos.  Although the final psak is that it doesn't, that is only after the first night where the assumption is that not everyone has wine.

Comment: @AdamMosheh A proof to this mehalech is that we say zeman on Yom Kippur even though we can't use a kos (SA 619:1).  The nosei kelim say that we don't use a kos and give it to a minor because he will continue to drink as an adult.  What is they're question?  Just say zeman does not require a kos! We see that the halacha of saying it without a kos is only when you have none.

Comment: Just to add another proof to the extensive repudiation of your view above, see משנה ברורה סימן קמ ס"ק ו 

 ואפילו שח מלה אחת וכמו בכל ברכת המצות או הנהנין דצריך לחזור ולברך אם הפסיק תיכף אחר הברכה אף אם יודע בבירור שלא הסיח דעתו דכיון שלא התחיל עדיין בהמצוה אין לה אח"כ על מה לחול